# Filtering results based on a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`Post`s belong to `User`s. `User`s have and belong to many roles (i.e., the tables we're dealing with here are `posts`, `users`, `roles`, and `roles_users`)

How can I select all posts written by a user who has the "Editor" role?

I.e., I want the database-driven version of

```
Post.all.select{|p| p.user.roles.map(&:name).include?("Editor")}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Post.all(:joins => {:user => :roles}, :conditions => ["roles.name = ?", "editor"])
```

Comment: This is correct, though `roles.name => ?` should be `roles.name = ?`

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :posts, :through => :users
end
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
Role.find(editor_id).posts
```